# How do I return multiple columns to a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to return to my view Product information(Name and Cost) and am running into the following error in my View code's foreach statement:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'ProductApp.Models.Product' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I seem to be missing something stupid simple.  Can anyone help me correct this?

Repository Code:

```
public class ProductRepository
{
  DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();

  public IQueryable<Product> FindAllProducts()
  {
     return db.Products;
  }

  public Product GetProductInfo(int id)
  {
     return db.Product.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Product_ID == id);
  }
}
```

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
      Product product = productRepository.GetProductInfo(id);

  return View("Index", product);
}
```

View Code:

```
<ul>
  <% foreach (var product in Model)
    { %>
      <li>
        <%: product.Product_Name%>
        which costs 
        <%: product.Product_Cost%>
        is available.
      </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you want to change your Controller code, you should be returning: productRepository.FindAllProducts();   instead of a single product.  That will match what your View expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view, look at the Model type.  Your first line in the view will tell you what type the View expects:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<myApp.Model.Product>" %>
```

The `Inherits` portion should tell you what type you expect.  In the above example it expects a single `Product` type.  This needs to match the type of the object that you pass into the View() method in your controller.

Your view probably has an inherit type that is something like this"

```
...Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<myApp.Model.Product>>"...
```

So you should make sure to return the list of items from your Controller.

Comment: After some retooling with my controller code and making sure the Inherits was set properly, it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You're looping over a single instance of a Product. You're passing to the view what gets returned from GetProductInfo, which is not a collection of products.

Comment: So in the Repository Code, I should have something like this:
public Product GetProductInfo()
{
 return db.Product();
}